# error related to ruby 1.9.3 and mongodb driver

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I have installed following the [tutorial](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/wiki/Tutorial)

```
$gem install mongo
Successfully installed mongo-1.8.6
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for mongo-1.8.6...
Installing RDoc documentation for mongo-1.8.6...
```

and

```
gem install bson_ext
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed bson_ext-1.8.6
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for bson_ext-1.8.6...
Installing RDoc documentation for bson_ext-1.8.6...
```

My mongo.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

require 'mongo'
include Mongo

mongo_client = MongoClient.new("localhost", 27017)
db = mongo_client.db("somedb")
coll = db.collection("somecoll")
```

When I ran mongo.rb, I got the error:

```
/home/askar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/bson_ext-1.8.6/ext/bson_ext/bson_ext/cbson.so: warning: method redefined; discarding old legal?
/home/askar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/bson-1.8.6/lib/bson/types/object_id.rb:39: warning: previous definition of legal? was here
/home/askar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/bson_ext-1.8.6/ext/bson_ext/bson_ext/cbson.so: warning: method redefined; discarding old from_string
/home/askar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/bson-1.8.6/lib/bson/types/object_id.rb:107: warning: previous definition of from_string was here
/home/askar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/bson_ext-1.8.6/ext/bson_ext/bson_ext/cbson.so: warning: method redefined; discarding old to_s
/home/askar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/bson-1.8.6/lib/bson/types/object_id.rb:119: warning: previous definition of to_s was here
/home/askar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/mongo-1.8.6/lib/mongo/util/pool_manager.rb:267: warning: mismatched indentations at 'end' with 'def' at 259
/home/askar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/mongo-1.8.6/lib/mongo/db.rb:339: warning: assigned but unused variable - e
/home/askar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/mongo-1.8.6/lib/mongo/gridfs/grid.rb:24: warning: assigned but unused variable - connection
/home/askar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/mongo-1.8.6/lib/mongo/gridfs/grid_file_system.rb:25: warning: assigned but unused variable - connection
/home/askar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/mongo-1.8.6/lib/mongo/util/write_concern.rb:32: warning: instance variable @legacy_write_concern not initialized
/home/askar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/mongo-1.8.6/lib/mongo/util/write_concern.rb:32: warning: instance variable @legacy_write_concern not initialized
/home/askar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/mongo-1.8.6/lib/mongo/util/write_concern.rb:32: warning: instance variable @legacy_write_concern not initialized
/home/askar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/mongo-1.8.6/lib/mongo/util/logging.rb:41: warning: instance variable @instrumenter not initialized
/home/askar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/mongo-1.8.6/lib/mongo/mongo_client.rb:523: warning: instance variable @max_message_size not initialized
/home/askar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/mongo-1.8.6/lib/mongo/mongo_client.rb:519: warning: instance variable @max_bson_size not initialized
/home/askar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/mongo-1.8.6/lib/mongo/mongo_client.rb:519: warning: instance variable @max_bson_size not initialized
/home/askar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/mongo-1.8.6/lib/mongo/util/write_concern.rb:32: warning: instance variable @legacy_write_concern not initialized
/home/askar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/mongo-1.8.6/lib/mongo/util/write_concern.rb:32: warning: instance variable @legacy_write_concern not initialized
```

But, in irb it seems ok:

```
$irb
1.9.3-p429 :001 > require 'mongo'
 => true 
1.9.3-p429 :002 > include Mongo
 => Object 
1.9.3-p429 :003 > mongo_client = MongoClient.new("localhost", 27017)
 => #<Mongo::MongoClient:0x00000001b5d618 @host="localhost", @port=27017, @id_lock=#<Mutex:0x00000001b5d550>, @primary=["localhost", 27017], @primary_pool=#<Mongo::Pool:0xdb22d4 @host=localhost @port=27017 @ping_time= 0/1 sockets available up=true>, @mongos=false, @tag_sets=[], @acceptable_latency=15, @slave_ok=nil, @ssl=nil, @unix=false, @socket_class=Mongo::TCPSocket, @auths=[], @pool_size=1, @pool_timeout=5.0, @op_timeout=nil, @connect_timeout=30, @logger=nil, @read=:primary, @write_concern={:w=>1, :j=>false, :fsync=>false, :wtimeout=>nil}, @read_primary=true, @max_bson_size=16777216, @max_message_size=48000000> 
1.9.3-p429 :004 > db = mongo_client.db("somedb")
 => #<Mongo::DB:0x00000001b66e48 @name="somedb", @connection=#<Mongo::MongoClient:0x00000001b5d618 @host="localhost", @port=27017, @id_lock=#<Mutex:0x00000001b5d550>, @primary=["localhost", 27017], @primary_pool=#<Mongo::Pool:0xdb22d4 @host=localhost @port=27017 @ping_time= 0/1 sockets available up=true>, @mongos=false, @tag_sets=[], @acceptable_latency=15, @slave_ok=nil, @ssl=nil, @unix=false, @socket_class=Mongo::TCPSocket, @auths=[], @pool_size=1, @pool_timeout=5.0, @op_timeout=nil, @connect_timeout=30, @logger=nil, @read=:primary, @write_concern={:w=>1, :j=>false, :fsync=>false, :wtimeout=>nil}, @read_primary=true, @max_bson_size=16777216, @max_message_size=48000000>, @strict=nil, @pk_factory=nil, @write_concern={:w=>1, :j=>false, :fsync=>false, :wtimeout=>nil}, @read=:primary, @tag_sets=[], @acceptable_latency=15, @cache_time=300> 
1.9.3-p429 :005 > coll = db.collection("somecoll")
 => #<Mongo::Collection:0x00000001ba9518 @name="somecoll", @db=#<Mongo::DB:0x00000001b66e48 @name="somedb", @connection=#<Mongo::MongoClient:0x00000001b5d618 @host="localhost", @port=27017, @id_lock=#<Mutex:0x00000001b5d550>, @primary=["localhost", 27017], @primary_pool=#<Mongo::Pool:0xdb22d4 @host=localhost @port=27017 @ping_time= 0/1 sockets available up=true>, @mongos=false, @tag_sets=[], @acceptable_latency=15, @slave_ok=nil, @ssl=nil, @unix=false, @socket_class=Mongo::TCPSocket, @auths=[], @pool_size=1, @pool_timeout=5.0, @op_timeout=nil, @connect_timeout=30, @logger=nil, @read=:primary, @write_concern={:w=>1, :j=>false, :fsync=>false, :wtimeout=>nil}, @read_primary=true, @max_bson_size=16777216, @max_message_size=48000000>, @strict=nil, @pk_factory=nil, @write_concern={:w=>1, :j=>false, :fsync=>false, :wtimeout=>nil}, @read=:primary, @tag_sets=[], @acceptable_latency=15, @cache_time=300>, @connection=#<Mongo::MongoClient:0x00000001b5d618 @host="localhost", @port=27017, @id_lock=#<Mutex:0x00000001b5d550>, @primary=["localhost", 27017], @primary_pool=#<Mongo::Pool:0xdb22d4 @host=localhost @port=27017 @ping_time= 0/1 sockets available up=true>, @mongos=false, @tag_sets=[], @acceptable_latency=15, @slave_ok=nil, @ssl=nil, @unix=false, @socket_class=Mongo::TCPSocket, @auths=[], @pool_size=1, @pool_timeout=5.0, @op_timeout=nil, @connect_timeout=30, @logger=nil, @read=:primary, @write_concern={:w=>1, :j=>false, :fsync=>false, :wtimeout=>nil}, @read_primary=true, @max_bson_size=16777216, @max_message_size=48000000>, @logger=nil, @cache_time=300, @cache={}, @write_concern={:w=>1, :j=>false, :fsync=>false, :wtimeout=>nil}, @read=:primary, @capped=nil, @tag_sets=[], @acceptable_latency=15, @pk_factory=BSON::ObjectId, @hint=nil> 
1.9.3-p429 :006 >
```

Actually when I run mongo.rb it should not showing anything because I'm just specifying what db and collection to use.

MongoDB version is 2.4.3.

Sorry that subject is not specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are not errors, they are warnings:

> /home/askar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/bson_ext-1.8.6/ext/bson_ext/bson_ext/cbson.so: **warning**: method redefined; discarding old legal?

They do not prevent you from executing the program, they just inform you about potential problems in the code: uninitialized instance variables, overridden methods and the like.

They show up because you are calling `ruby` with the `-w` option. You can use the same options with `irb`:

```
$ irb -w
irb> require 'mongodb'
/home/toro2k/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bson_ext-1.8.6/ext/bson_ext/bson_ext/cbson.so: warning: method redefined; discarding old legal?
...
...
```

Comment: Thanks! Should I care about this warnings or it's ok to ignore?

Comment: Long story made short: don't ignore warnings in you own code. In this case they come from `mongo` code, let its author cope with them.

Comment: tl;dr - these warnings are harmless, but we've already made a fix to the mongo gem to suppress these warnings. You can track the issue here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/RUBY-620